# Rails and mysql Cluster disk data

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I would like to know whether anybody has deployed a Rails APP + Mysql cluster, saving the data on disk space.

I saw a provider as [brightbox](http://www.brightbox.co.uk/), doing the same.

There is no much info, as well as gems/plugins to work with.

Comment: Do you mean the MySQL cluster engine? Or providers that support it? Rails doesn't really concern itself with the storage engine of your database.

Comment: I am not interesting on providers, i wanna do self-deployment of mysql cluster "ENGINE=NDBCLUSTER" + Data Disk-based + Rails APP. I guess AR Migrations won't work on the same way by default. I am also not sure how disk-based data will perform.